# Can firestore generate the UUID as documentId automatically for me

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uuid

I want the document id as UUID but I want that firestore should create the documentId for me every time I am saving the data, not default id I want the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't set a default format. You would have to specify it while adding the document. So instead of `collection.add()` you need to use `collection.doc(uuid.v4()).set()`

> When you use set() to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create.

Documentation: [Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)